# Add callback method of second form to existing buttons eventhandler on main form

Tags: c#, events, callback, delegates, eventhandler

Actually I have a simple question. When searching I only find slightly different issues answered.

I have a main form containing controls where the user gives input. The main form also has some control buttons. One of them is "ShowPreview" and one is "WorkOn".

After clicking "ShowPreview" some checks are run and if OK the user's input is transferred then to another form called preview where the input is presented more nicely.
By doubleclicking on the preview form, it closes. 
But the user could go back to work on his or her input by clicking on the main form button "WorkOn" without prior closing the preview form.

So I want to add a call back method to the click event of the button WorkOn that closes the preview form – if still open. The thing is, it could be closed and non-existent at this point or it could still be open.

All examples out there tell you to first implement a delegate type, create an event using this delegate and register your callback method.

But when I doubleclick on a button in VS (here on my main form) a click event handler is actually generated for that button and under cover a delegate is, too. So I figure the best would be to use the button's existing click event and add my closing method of the preview form as a callback method to it. If the preview form does not exist at this time (because the user actually doubleclicked it and thus closed it already), I suppose its callback method won't be registered any longer. Would it?
I don't quite see where I could do this and how this is routinely done.
It feels I should just register an event handling method of the preview form that conforms to .NETs event handling methods signature to my WorkOn button's  click event.

```
private void buttonPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveVariables();
    pv = new Preview();
    transferVariableInput(pv);
    if (pv.PreviewShow())   // checks done in PreviewShow then shown
    {
        this.buttonSave.Visible = true;
        this.buttonWorkOn.Visible = true;
        // some other buttons set to visible = false here
    }
}

private void buttonWorkOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // When this buttons click event occurs I want to check whether the 
     // preview form still exists and if it does it should be closed.
     this.buttonWorkOn.Visible = false;
     this.buttonSave.Visible = false;

     this.buttonOpen.Visible = true;
     this.buttonPreview.Visible = true;
     this.tabContactInfos.Enabled = true;
}
```

Thank you for elucidating.
Andi

Comment: You need to make your `pv` variable a field of your class so you can use it later to call the Close() method.  Set it back to null by subscribing the FormClosed event.

Answer (score 0):

as at first I was stuck, I reworded my question.
Then I solved it myself.
[Please click here to open the URL with the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534749/where-do-i-find-event-declarations-in-visual-studio-solved)